# Enabling posting to Twitter/Facebook/Skydrive and others from Windows Phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

Which frameworks are out there to enable your Windows Phone app to:

- Post directly into your twitter profile
- Post directly into your facebook status
- Access your SkyDrive account

Please state the name of the framework and a link to the source code, say on Codeplex

For facebook, there is this [C# Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: try mahapps library for twitter

Answer (score 1):

To post on Twitter and/or Facebook, you can simply use the [ShareStatusTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) class (this will use the accounts already on the phone). To access the SkyDrive account, you can use the [LiveSDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx).